# Chocolatey app install failure with the error message of The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: windows, installation, chocolatey

Chocolaty Cannot install packages.
I cannot install  any packages from chocolatey package manager
here is the full command prompt message

C:\WINDOWS\system32>choco install winrar -dv
    Chocolatey v0.10.11
    Chocolatey is running on Windows v 10.0.17134.0
    Attempting to delete file "C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/choco.exe.old".
    Attempting to delete file "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco.exe.old".
    Command line: "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\choco.exe" install winrar -dv
    Received arguments: install winrar -dv
    RemovePendingPackagesTask is now ready and waiting for PreRunMessage.
    Sending message 'PreRunMessage' out if there are subscribers...
    [Pending] Removing all pending packages that should not be considered installed...
    The source 'https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/' evaluated to a 'normal' source type

```
NOTE: Hiding sensitive configuration data! Please double and triple
 check to be sure no sensitive data is shown, especially if copying
 output to a gist for review.

Configuration: CommandName='install'|
CacheLocation='C:\Users\irrem\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey'|
ContainsLegacyPackageInstalls='True'|
CommandExecutionTimeoutSeconds='2700'|WebRequestTimeoutSeconds='30'|
Sources='https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/'|SourceType='normal'|
Debug='True'|Verbose='True'|Trace='False'|Force='False'|Noop='False'|
HelpRequested='False'|UnsuccessfulParsing='False'|RegularOutput='True'|
QuietOutput='False'|PromptForConfirmation='True'|AcceptLicense='False'|
AllowUnofficialBuild='False'|Input='winrar'|AllVersions='False'|
SkipPackageInstallProvider='False'|PackageNames='winrar'|
Prerelease='False'|ForceX86='False'|OverrideArguments='False'|
NotSilent='False'|ApplyPackageParametersToDependencies='False'|
ApplyInstallArgumentsToDependencies='False'|IgnoreDependencies='False'|
AllowMultipleVersions='False'|AllowDowngrade='False'|
ForceDependencies='False'|Information.PlatformType='Windows'|
Information.PlatformVersion='10.0.17134.0'|
Information.PlatformName='Windows 10'|
Information.ChocolateyVersion='0.10.11.0'|
Information.ChocolateyProductVersion='0.10.11'|
Information.FullName='choco, Version=0.10.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=79d02ea9cad655eb'|

Information.Is64BitOperatingSystem='True'|
Information.Is64BitProcess='True'|Information.IsInteractive='True'|
Information.UserName='irrem'|
Information.UserDomainName='DESKTOP-8FVQM8H'|
Information.IsUserAdministrator='True'|
Information.IsUserSystemAccount='False'|
Information.IsUserRemoteDesktop='False'|
Information.IsUserRemote='True'|
Information.IsProcessElevated='True'|
Information.IsLicensedVersion='False'|Information.LicenseType='Foss'|
Features.AutoUninstaller='True'|Features.ChecksumFiles='True'|
Features.AllowEmptyChecksums='False'|
Features.AllowEmptyChecksumsSecure='True'|
Features.FailOnAutoUninstaller='False'|
Features.FailOnStandardError='False'|Features.UsePowerShellHost='True'|
Features.LogEnvironmentValues='False'|Features.LogWithoutColor='False'|
Features.VirusCheck='False'|
Features.FailOnInvalidOrMissingLicense='False'|
Features.IgnoreInvalidOptionsSwitches='True'|
Features.UsePackageExitCodes='True'|
Features.UseFipsCompliantChecksums='False'|
Features.ShowNonElevatedWarnings='True'|
Features.ShowDownloadProgress='True'|
Features.StopOnFirstPackageFailure='False'|
Features.UseRememberedArgumentsForUpgrades='False'|
Features.IgnoreUnfoundPackagesOnUpgradeOutdated='False'|
Features.RemovePackageInformationOnUninstall='False'|
Features.ScriptsCheckLastExitCode='False'|
ListCommand.LocalOnly='False'|
ListCommand.IdOnly='False'|ListCommand.IncludeRegistryPrograms='False'|
ListCommand.PageSize='25'|ListCommand.Exact='False'|
ListCommand.ByIdOnly='False'|ListCommand.ByTagOnly='False'|
ListCommand.IdStartsWith='False'|ListCommand.OrderByPopularity='False'|
ListCommand.ApprovedOnly='False'|
ListCommand.DownloadCacheAvailable='False'|
ListCommand.NotBroken='False'|
ListCommand.IncludeVersionOverrides='False'|
UpgradeCommand.FailOnUnfound='False'|
UpgradeCommand.FailOnNotInstalled='False'|
UpgradeCommand.NotifyOnlyAvailableUpgrades='False'|
UpgradeCommand.ExcludePrerelease='False'|
NewCommand.AutomaticPackage='False'|
NewCommand.UseOriginalTemplate='False'|SourceCommand.Command='unknown'|
SourceCommand.Priority='0'|SourceCommand.BypassProxy='False'|
SourceCommand.AllowSelfService='False'|
SourceCommand.VisibleToAdminsOnly='False'|
FeatureCommand.Command='unknown'|ConfigCommand.Command='unknown'|
PinCommand.Command='unknown'|OutdatedCommand.IgnorePinned='False'|
Proxy.BypassOnLocal='True'|

_ Chocolatey:ChocolateyInstallCommand - Normal Run Mode _
Installing the following packages:
winrar
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
**[NuGet] An error occurred while loading packages from 'https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/': The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.**
winrar not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
 Source(s): 'https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
 NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.
If the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify `--pre`,
 the package may not be found.
Please see https://chocolatey.org/docs/troubleshooting for more
 assistance.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - winrar - winrar not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
 Source(s): 'https://chocolatey.org/api/v2/'
 NOTE: When you specify explicit sources, it overrides default sources.
If the package version is a prerelease and you didn't specify `--pre`,
 the package may not be found.
Please see https://chocolatey.org/docs/troubleshooting for more
 assistance.
Sending message 'PostRunMessage' out if there are subscribers...
Exiting with 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The Chocolatey Community Repoository was having issues around that time. Are you still having issues now?

To keep up to date with all the Chocolatey notifications use:

- Twitter - https://twitter.com/chocolateynuget
- Gitter - https://github.com/chocolatey/choco#chat-room
- Google Groups - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/chocolatey (and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/chocolatey-announce for announcements)

The issues were announced on those mediums.